# How to impliment new GPS & wifi enable dialgoue in android

Tags: android, google-maps, dialog, gps

i am using the GoogleAPI Client and locationRequest class to impliment this, but not showung the dialogue, in logcat it showing error "missing R.string.google_key", i need help how to impliment this and which google key is needed for this.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            //**************************
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
            //**************************

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                            // requests here.
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
//                            // a dialog.
//                            try {
//                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
//                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
//                                status.startResolutionForResult(
//                                        Activity.class, 1000);
//                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
//                                // Ignore the error.
//                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });             }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code its perfectly working for me


private static int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 200;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;  
private AppLocationService appLocationService;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.reserve_user_screen);
appLocationService = new AppLocationService(ReserveUser.this);
showLocationAlertDialog(ReserveUser.this);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void showLocationAlertDialog(final Activity activity) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        Object obj = LocationRequest.create();
                        ((LocationRequest) (obj)).setPriority(100);
                        ((LocationRequest) (obj)).setInterval(30000L);
                        ((LocationRequest) (obj)).setFastestInterval(5000L);
                        obj = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(
                                ((LocationRequest) (obj))).setAlwaysShow(true);

                        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                                mGoogleApiClient,
                                ((LocationSettingsRequest.Builder) (obj)).build())
                                .setResultCallback(
                                        new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onResult(
                                                    LocationSettingsResult locationsettingsresult) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                Status status;
                                                Log.e("result",
                                                        (new StringBuilder())
                                                                .append("=")
                                                                .append(locationsettingsresult
                                                                        .getStatus())
                                                                .toString());
                                                status = locationsettingsresult
                                                        .getStatus();
                                                locationsettingsresult
                                                        .getLocationSettingsStates();
                                                status.getStatusCode();

                                                try {
                                                    status.startResolutionForResult(
                                                            ReserveUser.this, 1000);

                                                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }

                                            }
                                        });
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                            "android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS"), 1);
                    return;

                }
            }

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(20000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
```

/***
*
*App location class
*
/

public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

```
protected LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 2;

public AppLocationService(Context context) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public Location getLocation(String provider) {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            return location;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: 1: i am getting the error of import on there classes
AppLocationService & ReserveUser.this.
2: Eror of Context on .addConnectionCallbacks(this).
3: should i need a google api key to use this dialogue.

Comment: now see above code and for ReserveUser.this use your class name

Comment: it is my logcat GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Comment: get config file from https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue

Comment: refer this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start?hl=en